# System.out.format in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a formatted output in Java but I'm having some trouble... I write for example:

```
System.out.format ("%d", 5);
```

but Eclipse underlines the word "format" and there is a marker at this line saying:

> The method format(String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, int).

Comment: Are you using Java 1.5+?

Comment: @Reimus the method `format(String, Object[])` was introduced in Java 5 I believe,  so the OP is probably using at least that version. It may be an old compiler bug when mixing varargs and autoboxing.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is that you are not using Java 1.5 or higher. Please check the version in your build. In Eclipse, this is:

- Right Click on the Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
- Choose Libraries tab, click on JRE System Library then choose Edit
- Change your execution environment to one that is Java 1.5 or higher in the drop down.

Comment: @assylias I wrote that last bit before I went and checked. I wasn't sure how OP could have gotten in that situation unless the method existed but autoboxing did not...

Comment: np - the compile error message is a bit weird because it seems to know that there is a format method, in which case the compiler is 1.5+...

Comment: Actually with Java 1.4 (I found an online compiler), the error is "*cannot resolve symbol : method format (java.lang.String,int) in class java.io.PrintStream*"